# SXA retrieve SiteInfo for another site (not the context site)

Tags: sxa, sitecore-api

In order to render alternate URL metadata, I need to get a SiteInfo object (`Sitecore.Web.SiteInfo`) for other sites apart from the context site.

I have tried to use

```
var otherSiteInfo = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISiteInfoResolver>().GetSiteInfo(otherSiteItem);
```

but this does not seem to work correctly. It returns the site named "website" (from the Sitecore.config).

One other thing I noticed with the above technique was that when getting the current site's SiteInfo, the site with the "web" database was returned, despite Sitecore.Context.Database being "master".

From this I assume that either a) I'm going about this the wrong way and using the wrong API or b) there is a bug with this part of SXA?

I'm using Sitecore 9.0.2 and SXA 1.8 rev. 181112.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me `Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextFactory.Sites` worked to get all sites.

If you need to know whether it is an SXA site or not, you can check for the property `IsSxaSite` (something like `x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Properties.Get("IsSxaSite")`)